# Multirow delete in mui-datatables how can i change the delete icon

Tags: reactjs

[image]I have MatrialUiTable  if I select any of the table row by Clicking the checkboxes. On the top right hand side of the table delete icon will  appear. But  I wanted different icon which will do the same deletion operation .Is there any solution to change the Icon in MuiTable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi row delete icon can be changed by using Custom Components. The code is mentioned in code sample.`

```
    const options = {
rowsSelected: rowsSelected,

customToolbarSelect: (selectedRows, displayData, setSelectedRows) => (
<div>
  <Tooltip title={"Delete"} cursor='pointer' className="mr-6">
  <Icon onClick={()=>DeleteRow(selectedRows)}  color="error">delete</Icon>
  </Tooltip>
  
  
</div>

),
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the delete icon from top during multiple rows select. use it.

```
customToolbarSelect: () => {},
```

Also for other task replacing delete icon. Try it

```
  const [selectedFabrics, setSelectedFabrics] = useState([])
customToolbarSelect: selectedRows => (
      <IconButton
        onClick={() => {
          const indexesToPrint = selectedRows.data.map((row, k) => row.dataIndex);
          let temp = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < fabricList.length; i++) {
            if (indexesToPrint.includes(i)) {
              temp.push(fabricList[i]['id']);
            }
          }
          setSelectedFabrics(temp);
        }}
        style={{
          marginRight: "24px",
          height: "48px",
          top: "50%",
          display: "block",
          position: "relative",
          transform: "translateY(-50%)",
        }}
      >
        {/* <EditIcon /> */}
        <span style={{marginTop: "23px"}}>Print QR Code</span> 
      </IconButton>
    ),
```